# Does "I'm worth your trust" sound natural?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

I was about to use the phrase "I'm worth your trust" in a company document, when I happened upon [this EnglishForums post](https://www.englishforums.com/English/WorthTrustTrusting/hgndg/post.htm), where a poster calls the expression "borderline acceptable."

Is there a problem with this expression? Does it sound strange? If so, what would be more acceptable alternatives?

Comment: It sounds slightly strange but as the other person said, 'borderline acceptable'.

Comment: @Deonyi what would you suggest as a better alternative?

Comment: Google "worthy of your trust" and "worth your trust", and check to see if the people using some of the examples sound competent.

Comment: It seems at least a few reputable sources (though not many) do use "worth your trust": https://www.npr.org/2014/10/03/353292500/whos-worth-your-trust-in-finchers-moody-atmospheric-gone-girl , https://www.lifehack.org/607801/how-to-tell-if-someone-is-worth-your-trust

Comment: That said, I'm a bit alarmed by its low usage frequency.

Answer (score 1):

Normal usage would be:

> I'm **worthy of** your trust.

when you want the other party to trust you.

> I'm **worth** your trust.

might be acceptable, but comes across as making a self-important valuation of yourself, as in

> I'm **worth** the $50,000 you are paying me.